How to change default cmap behavior with plot_surface()?
How can I use cmap to have a color gradient determined by x values rather than by z values?

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 20
s = 0.05

y = np.linspace(-s, s, n)
z = np.linspace(-s, s, n)
Y, Z = np.meshgrid(y, z)
dist = (Y**6 * Z**2) ** 0.1

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))
ax.plot_surface(dist, Y, Z, cmap='viridis')
ax.set(aspect='equal', xlabel='x', ylabel='y', zlabel='z')


Maybe this is a dumb suggestion, but why can't you plot X as if it were Z and then rotate the plot, if you want?

@CamiloMartínezM.: I don't know how to do that, can you post an answer?

I was apparently successful in using another parameter: facecolors.

A color of the viridis gradient is associated to each face based on the value of dist. This requires the normalization of dist to the interval [0, 1]:
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors
d_min, d_max = np.min(dist), np.max(dist)
norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=d_min, vmax=d_max)
facecolors = cm.viridis(norm(dist))

Then the plot instruction becomes:
ax.plot_surface(dist, Y, Z, facecolors=facecolors, shade=False)

shade=False which is implied when using cmap must be added explicitly.

While this works, I expect someone will suggest a more concise solution I'll be able to select.

You can indeed swap dist and Z then rotate the diagram with that line ax.view_init(150, 0,90) (elevation, azimuth and roll in degree). Feel free to change the three values to rotate the plot as you like.
The total program would be
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 20
s = 0.05

y = np.linspace(-s, s, n)
z = np.linspace(-s, s, n)
Y, Z = np.meshgrid(y, z)
dist = (Y**6 * Z**2) ** 0.1

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))
ax.plot_surface(Z, Y, dist, cmap='viridis')  # CHANGED
ax.set(aspect='equal', xlabel='x', ylabel='y', zlabel='z')

ax.view_init(150, 0,90) # CHANGED


Thanks. +1 for the idea and effort. This bypass is good when the surface is the only plot. But with multiple plots, which is my case, other plots have to be adjusted, x and z values need to be swapped. It may be acceptable, but in my it may rather cause confusion.
